# How can I make git sample hooks not executable by default?

Tags: git, permissions, hook

How can I configure git **not** to make `.git/hooks/*.sample` executable by default in a new post-1.6 git repository?

I don't have permission to:

```
$ chmod -x /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/*
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want them not to be executable? They won't be run until you rename them to not include the `.sample`.

Comment: They were changed to be disabled by being named `.sample` instead of by not being executable, because on certain platforms (like Windows under Cygwin), they would be marked executable even if they weren't supposed to be; naming them `.sample` was a more robust way to ensure they wouldn't be accidentally enabled. Leaving them executable means there's still only one step to enable them, which is renaming them to remove the `.sample`.

Comment: Correct. That was a wise modification. But it's just the tree seems cleaner to me that way. Thanks.

Comment: That is, their being named `.sample` and not being executable at the same time.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to check, in case there was some other problem you were trying to solve. If it's just personal preference, then my answer should do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own template directory by copying `/usr/share/git-core/templates/` into somwhere within your home directory. Add to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[init]
    templatedir = /path/to/my/templates
```

In your own copy, you should be able to change the permissions as you would like.

Comment: @NicolaiRostov Glad I could help! Since it looks like you're new here, I'd like to point out the [FAQ on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). In particular, it's generally good form to mark an answer as accepted if it answers your question, by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question.

Comment: Sure, I will do that soon. It's just I need at least reputation 15 before doing that, and I'm currently 6. Thanks again.

Comment: @NicolaiRostov I don't believe you need 15 reputation to accept an answer; you only need 15 reputation in order to be able to vote. You can always accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: @NicolaiRostov No problem! StackOverflow can be a little confusing at first, but you'll get the hang of it. You're ahead of most users their first day, given that you have used Markdown correctly and edited your question.